# Ember.js: 'init' hook being called twice on ObjectController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I was fiddling around with Ember and I came across something that confused me.

I have an ArrayController (`Index`) with an item controller (`Post`).  For the `init` hook on the `Post` item controller, I have it send a debug line out to the console.  This debug statement is being sent twice for each post, and I can't figure out why.

**Code on JSBin:**
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/momikuto/14/edit

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{each controller itemViewClass="App.PostView"}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
  POST {{id}}<br />
</script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'post',
  templateName: 'index',

  addPost: function (id) {
    this.pushObject(App.PostController.create({ id: id }));
  }
});

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  debug: function () {
    console.log('init for post ' + this.get('id'));
  }.on('init')
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function () {
    this.get('controller').addPost(1);
    this.get('controller').addPost(2);
  }
});

App.PostView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  templateName: 'post'
});
```

**Output:**

```
init for post 1
init for post 1
init for post 2
init for post 2
```

If I remove post 2 and only use post 1, I just get `init for post 1` twice.  If I add a post, I get all three of them twice.  The number of Post objects in the ArrayControl does not seem to have anything to do with the problem.

---

I saw one post on the Ember Github, but it was closed after it was assumed to not be an Ember issue.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating it twice.  You have `itemController` set on your `IndexController` and you're actually creating the controller in the `addPost` function.

You shouldn't ever need to create a controller instance yourself, except for some strange edge cases.  Ember will create the `itemControler` instance for you when you `pushObject` so you don't need to manually `create`.